# Google Maps e Jquery problemas

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-ui

Estou montando um site com jQuery UI e google maps. Minha div do map fica dentro de outra div (tab) do Jquery. Não sei se existe algum conflito entre o jquery-ui e o google maps, pois não funciona só mostra uma caixa cinza com os controles de zoom e street view, mas o mapa não renderiza.

Já pesquisei bastante na net e não encontro uma solução viável, o mais perto de uma solução que cheguei foi pra usar uma função de *resize* do google, mas não está funcionando também.

Quando eu tiro a div do mapa de dentro das div´s de TAB do Jquery tudo funciona, porém o site fica uma bagunça. Estou usando esse plugin para o mapa: `jquery-ui-map`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function carrega_map() {
        // Also works with: var yourStartLatLng = '59.3426606750, 18.0736160278';
        var yourStartLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(59.3426606750, 18.0736160278);
        $('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': yourStartLatLng});
    }
</script>
```

Comment: O google tem um limite de visualizações por dia, quando ultrapassa esse período, ele cria uma caixa cinza, vc precisa criar uma chave API e habilitar, recomendo que vc utilize uma versão segura ssl: https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=pt-br&libraries=places

Comment: Não aparece nada no console? Considere incluir um [mcve](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), deste jeito fica difícil reproduzir.

Comment: Poderia mostrar o que aparece no console?

Comment: Prezados, obrigado pelas respostas...acabei mudando o plugin do map usando agora um chamado gmap... mas o problema persistiu depois d muita pesquisa descobrir que era um problema na definição dos atributos de width e heigh da div onde o mapa sera renderizado.

Comment: o software ainda esta em desenvolvimento ..logo esteja em produção vou colocar o link aqui pra vcs conhecerem o trabalho e se possível ajudar a divulgar...