# Google Maps aparecendo tudo cinza

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

Desenvolvi um html mas encontro problema pra fazer ele funcionar, na minha lógica está tudo certo mas não roda corretamente.

Em que estou errando?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//PT" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Roteirizador Matteusin</title>
</head>
 
  <body>

  <div id="dvMapa" style="height: 600px; width: 80%;"> </div>  
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
   
   var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

   var _mapPoints = new Array();
   var _directionsRenderer = '';
   var zoom_option = 6;
   var LegPoints = new Array();
   var map;
   function InitializeMap() {

    _directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    var myOptions = {
     zoom: zoom_option,
     zoomControl: true,
     disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
     streetViewControl: false,
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(-8.598882, -55.641439),
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMapa"), myOptions);
    _directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
    _directionsRenderer.setOptions({ draggable: true });

    google.maps.event.addListener(_directionsRenderer, 'directions_changed', function() {
    var myroute = _directionsRenderer.directions.routes[0];
    CreateRoute(myroute);
    zoom_option = map.getZoom();
    });
 
    drawRoute();
   }


   function CreateRoute(myroute) {
    var index = 0;
    if (_mapPoints.length > 10)
    {
     index = _mapPoints.length - 10;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
     saveLegPoints(myroute.legs[i], index);
     index = index + 1;
    }
   }

   function saveLegPoints(leg, index) {
   var points = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < leg.steps.length; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < leg.steps[i].lat_lngs.length; j++) {
      points.push(leg.steps[i].lat_lngs[j]);
     }
    }
    LegPoints[index] = points;
   }

   function drawPreviousRoute(Legs) {
    var segPointValue = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < Legs; i++) {
     var innerArry = LegPoints[i];
     for (var j = 0; j < innerArry.length; j++) {
      segPointValue.push(innerArry[j]);
     }
     //addPreviousMarker(innerArry[0]);
    }
    var polyOptions = {
     path: segPointValue,
     strokeColor: '#F75C54',
     strokeWeight: 3
    };
    var poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
    poly.setMap(map);
   }

   function addPreviousMarker(myLatlng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: myLatlng,
     icon: "Images/red-circle.png",
     title: ""
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
   }

   function getRoutePointsAndWaypoints(Points) {
    if (Points.length <= 10) {
     drawRoutePointsAndWaypoints(Points);
    }
    else {
     var newPoints = new Array();
     var startPoint = Points.length - 10;
     var Legs = Points.length - 10;
     for (var i = startPoint; i < Points.length; i++) {
      newPoints.push(Points[i]);
     }
     drawRoutePointsAndWaypoints(newPoints);
     drawPreviousRoute(Legs);
    }
   }


   function drawRoutePointsAndWaypoints(Points) {
    var _waypoints = new Array();

    if (Points.length > 2)
    {
     for (var j = 1; j < Points.length - 1; j++) {
      var address = Points[j];
      if (address !== "") {
       _waypoints.push({
        location: address,
        stopover: true
       });
      }
     }  
     drawRoute(Points[0], Points[Points.length - 1], _waypoints);
    } else if (Points.length > 1) {
     drawRoute(Points[_mapPoints.length - 2], Points[Points.length - 1], _waypoints);
    } else {
     drawRoute(Points[_mapPoints.length - 1], Points[Points.length - 1], _waypoints);
    }
   }

   function drawRoute() {
    var _request = '';
     _request = {
      origin: 'Rua das Bananeiras, Pq. Santana - Santana de Parnaiba',
      destination: 'Peixes, Parque Santana - SP',
      waypoints: [{location: 'Rua Virgem, Parque Santana - SP'}, {location: 'Rua Touro, Parque Santana - SP'}],
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
     };
  
    directionsService.route(_request, function(_response, _status) {
     if (_status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      _directionsRenderer.setDirections(_response);
     }
    });
   }
   
  </script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=false&callback=InitializeMap" async defer></script>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A lógica não deve estar errada, o que acontece é que o google maps, exige uma API Key e essa API Key tem um limite de acessos dependendo do usuário, você pode usar uma api com "https" igual ao do site do ITAÚ que terá um acesso ilimitado, creio eu.

Comment: https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=pt-br

Comment: veja se isso te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74934/google-maps-e-jquery-problemas

Comment: Bom dia amigos. Infelizmente não deu certo, apliquei uma KEY, hoje foi o primeiro acesso do dia e não deu certo. Tenho esse código separado por .html e .js, lá eles funcionam normalmente, isso daí é uma tentativa de unificar os dois

Comment: Vou ver o que posso fazer pra te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu arrumei  para que o mapa seja exibido, porém, há um problema no **route**, não sei se estão corretos, mas você pode procurar mais informações aqui, eu acredito que você esteja excedendo o limite de 8 **waypoints**:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-travel-modes

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//PT" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Roteirizador Matteusin</title>
</head>
 
  <body>

 <div id="dvMapa" style="height: 600px; width: 80%;"> </div>  
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  
  var _directionsRenderer,
      directionsService,
      map,
      myOptions,
      _request;

  var _mapPoints = new Array();
  
  var zoom_option = 6;
  var LegPoints = new Array();    

  function InitializeMap() {

   var _directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
   myOptions = {
    zoom: zoom_option,
    zoomControl: true,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-8.598882, -55.641439),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMapa"), myOptions);
   _directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
   _directionsRenderer.setOptions({ draggable: true });

   google.maps.event.addListener(_directionsRenderer, 'directions_changed', function() {
   var myroute = _directionsRenderer.directions.routes[0];
   CreateRoute(myroute);
   zoom_option = map.getZoom();
   });
         
                  drawRoute();
   
  }

  function CreateRoute(myroute) {
   var index = 0;
   if (_mapPoints.length > 10)
   {
    index = _mapPoints.length - 10;
   }

   for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
    saveLegPoints(myroute.legs[i], index);
    index = index + 1;
   }
  }

  function saveLegPoints(leg, index) {
  var points = new Array();
   for (var i = 0; i < leg.steps.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < leg.steps[i].lat_lngs.length; j++) {
     points.push(leg.steps[i].lat_lngs[j]);
    }
   }
   LegPoints[index] = points;
  }

  function drawPreviousRoute(Legs) {
   var segPointValue = new Array();
   for (var i = 0; i < Legs; i++) {
    var innerArry = LegPoints[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < innerArry.length; j++) {
     segPointValue.push(innerArry[j]);
    }
    //addPreviousMarker(innerArry[0]);
   }
   var polyOptions = {
    path: segPointValue,
    strokeColor: '#F75C54',
    strokeWeight: 3
   };
   var poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
   poly.setMap(map);
  }

  function addPreviousMarker(myLatlng) {
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    icon: "Images/red-circle.png",
    title: ""
   });
   marker.setMap(map);
  }

  function getRoutePointsAndWaypoints(Points) {
   if (Points.length <= 10) {
    drawRoutePointsAndWaypoints(Points);
   }
   else {
    var newPoints = new Array();
    var startPoint = Points.length - 10;
    var Legs = Points.length - 10;
    for (var i = startPoint; i < Points.length; i++) {
     newPoints.push(Points[i]);
    }
    drawRoutePointsAndWaypoints(newPoints);
    drawPreviousRoute(Legs);
   }
  }


  function drawRoutePointsAndWaypoints(Points) {
   var _waypoints = new Array();

   if (Points.length > 2)
   {
    for (var j = 1; j < Points.length - 1; j++) {
     var address = Points[j];
     if (address !== "") {
      _waypoints.push({
       location: address,
       stopover: true
      });
     }
    }  
    drawRoute(Points[0], Points[Points.length - 1], _waypoints);
   } else if (Points.length > 1) {
    drawRoute(Points[_mapPoints.length - 2], Points[Points.length - 1], _waypoints);
   } else {
    drawRoute(Points[_mapPoints.length - 1], Points[Points.length - 1], _waypoints);
   }
  }

  function drawRoute() {
    var _request = {
     origin: 'Rua das Bananeiras, Pq. Santana - Santana de Parnaiba',
     destination: 'Peixes, Parque Santana - SP',
     waypoints: [{location: 'Rua Virgem, Parque Santana - SP'}, {location: 'Rua Touro, Parque Santana - SP'}],
     optimizeWaypoints: true,
     travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

   directionsService.route(_request, function(_response, _status) {
    if (_status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
     _directionsRenderer.setDirections(_response);
    }
   });
  }

 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=false&callback=InitializeMap" async defer></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Boa tarde Ivan. Muito obrigado, vou tentar rever ajustar com base no que vc me passou. Mas eu consegui fazer uma gambiarra pra unificar os scrips com o HTML e deu certo, vou trabalhar nos ajustes agora, conforme vc me passou aí. Muito obrigado :D